# Where condition on QueryBuilder greenDao android

Tags: android, query-builder, greendao

I am new in android and decided to learn greenDao ORM and use it in my test project.

I am creating a list of User objects. Each user onject can have multiple childs. So I keep userId in child objects to be able to find user's child.

Each child has a phone number. these phone numbers are unique. so, when I want to insert a child for a user I should check that the child's phone number should not exist in table.

To do this I made a QueryBuilder that gets all child objects from database.`QueryBuilder<Child> childQuery = childDao().queryBuilder()
                     .where(ChildeDao.Properties.UserId.eq(child.getUserId()));`

this is used to get all children. Now if I want to add a new child, I get its phoneNumber and check below condition. If the size of this list is equal to zero it means that I can add child but if it is greater than zero it means that this child exists:

```
childQuery.where(ChildDao.Properties.PhoneNumber.eq(phoneNumber)).list().size()
```

Note that the phoneNumber is the new child phoneNumber.

But my problem is that when I get child List by the first query its size is 10 which is exactly correct in my case and then when I check the condition by second code, suddenly the  size of childQuery changes to one or zero. (depends on that the new child's phone number exists in DB or not.)
Here is exactly what I have written:

```
    QueryBuilder<Child> childQuery = childDao().queryBuilder()
                 .where(ChildeDao.Properties.UserId.eq(child.getUserId()));
    for(int i = 0; i < newChildrenList.size(); i++)
    {
         String phoneNumber = newChildrenList.get(i).getPhoneNumber();

         if(childQuery.where(ChildDao.Properties.PhoneNumber.eq(phoneNumber)).list().size()==0){
               addChildToDB();
       }
     }
```

So my question is that I dont know what is wrong with the code above. Why is childQuery affected by where condition? how should I prevent its change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it is greenDao's feature to add conditions (Where()) to existing `QueryBuilder` dynamically.

So when you are checking `childQuery.where(ChildDao.Properties.PhoneNumber.eq(phoneNumber))`, it adds condition to the original query.

One way to prevent it is to make a new variable inside the loop:

```
for(...){
    QueryBuilder<Child> child = childQuery;
    if(child.where(ChildDao.Properties..PhoneNumber.eq(phoneNumber)).list().size()==0){
        addChildToDB();
   }
}
```

or you might as well put the childQuery inside:

```
if(childDao().queryBuilder()
             .where(ChildeDao.Properties.UserId.eq(child.getUserId()), 
                    ChildDao.Properties.PhoneNumber.eq(phoneNumber))
             .list().size() == 0){
    addChildToDB();
}
```

Comment: adding `.where()` into `QueryBuilder` only adds parameter to `List<WhereCondition>`. The query itself won't be executed until you call `.list()`. I assume the difference between the two is insignificant.

Comment: FYI, you can use `.count()` instead of `.list().size()` if you don't need to access the data that is fetched.

Comment: Yes, I mean you can shorten `.list().size()` into `.count()`.